# LOADING RDF with TDBLOADER on OSX YOSEMITE BLOCKS without any message

Tags: assembly, rdf, jena, tdbloader

First of all a happy new year 2015 to everybody!

I am a newbye in Jena and the first thing I do taking an RDF processing tool is loading some data into some separate graphs to test later SPARQL access on them.

```
My env is YOSEMITE with Java 1.8 (JDK 1.8)
```

I would like to load an RDF data set - here  in the file named "pp_project_semweb.rdf" into a graph named http://semweb.ch/SEMWEB using the following command line:

```
tdbloader --tdb=jenatest.ttl --verbose
```

And the following Assembler file:

```
@prefix dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model      .

<#dataset> rdf:type tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "DB" ;
    ja:namedGraph
        [ ja:graphName      <http://semweb.ch/SEMWEB> ;
          ja:graph          <#graph_semweb> ] ;
  .
<#graph_semweb> a ja:MemoryModel ;
      ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:/Users/fabio/Documents/workspace/JenaPrototype/Assembling/JenaRDFData/thesauri/pp_project_semweb.rdf>] ;
    .
```

What the loader says is the following:

```
Java maximum memory: 954728448
symbol:http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ#constantBNodeLabels = true
symbol:http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ#regexImpl = symbol:http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ#javaRegex
symbol:http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ#stageGenerator = com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.solver.StageGeneratorDirectTDB@313ac989
symbol:http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ#strictSPARQL = false
symbol:http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ#enablePropertyFunctions = true
13:41:53 INFO  loader               :: -- Start triples data phase
13:41:53 INFO  loader               :: ** Load empty triples table
13:41:53 INFO  loader               :: -- Start quads data phase
13:41:53 INFO  loader               :: ** Load empty quads table
13:41:53 INFO  loader               :: Load: - -- 2015/01/02 13:41:53 CET
```

Then the tdbloader BLOCKS ... it comsumes no CPU and you can wait forever...

Does anybody know what is here wrong?

Could anyone please tell me ho I can debug or look at some logfiles on that?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong, you just haven't explicitly provided anything to load. In this situation `tdbloader` will take triples from `<STDIN>`, until it reached `EOF`. Try typing `ctrl-d` which signals end-of-transmission to exit.

Given what you're trying to do all you need is:

```
$ tdbloader2 --loc DB /Users/fabio/Documents/workspace/JenaPrototype/Assembling/JenaRDFData/thesauri/pp_project_semweb.rdf
```

(tdbloader2 is a faster variant of the same tool, `DB` is the directory holding the rdf database)

Then you can query with:

```
$ tdbquery --loc DB --query my_query_file.rq
```